# Using geom_bar() with categorical Y axis values and X axis date values

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have climate data I would like to plot by each weather station over the course of 5 months. I would like to use geom_bar() with different colors to denote the different weather classifications, ultimately creating a plot with the Y-axis being categorical Station names, and the X-axis being the date.

```
Data <- structure(list(Date = structure(c(17046, 17047, 17048, 17049, 
17050, 17051, 17052, 17053, 17054, 17055, 17056, 17057, 17058, 
17059, 17060, 17061, 17062, 17063, 17064, 17065, 17066, 17067, 
17068, 17069, 17070, 17071, 17072, 17073, 17074, 17046, 17047, 
17048, 17049, 17050, 17051, 17052, 17053, 17054, 17055, 17056, 
17057, 17058, 17059, 17060, 17061, 17062, 17063, 17064, 17065, 
17066, 17067, 17068, 17069, 17070, 17071, 17072, 17073, 17074, 
17046, 17047, 17048, 17049, 17050, 17051, 17052, 17053, 17054, 
17055, 17056, 17057, 17058, 17059, 17060, 17061, 17062, 17063, 
17064, 17065, 17066, 17067, 17068, 17069, 17070, 17071, 17072, 
17073, 17074, 17046, 17047, 17048, 17049, 17050, 17051, 17052, 
17053, 17054, 17055, 17056, 17057, 17058, 17059, 17060, 17061, 
17062, 17063, 17064, 17065, 17066, 17067, 17068, 17069, 17070, 
17071, 17072, 17073, 17074, 17046, 17047, 17048, 17049, 17050, 
17051, 17052, 17053, 17054, 17055, 17056, 17057, 17058, 17059, 
17060, 17061, 17062, 17063, 17064, 17065, 17066, 17067, 17068, 
17069, 17070, 17071, 17072, 17073, 17074, 17046, 17047, 17048, 
17049, 17050, 17051, 17052, 17053, 17054, 17055, 17056, 17057, 
17058, 17059, 17060, 17061, 17062, 17063, 17064, 17065, 17066, 
17067, 17068, 17069, 17070, 17071, 17072, 17073, 17074, 17046, 
17047, 17048, 17049, 17050, 17051, 17052, 17053, 17054, 17055, 
17056, 17057, 17058, 17059, 17060, 17061, 17062, 17063, 17064, 
17065, 17066, 17067, 17068, 17069, 17070, 17071, 17072, 17073, 
17074, 17046, 17047, 17048, 17049, 17050, 17051, 17052, 17053, 
17054, 17055, 17056, 17057, 17058, 17059, 17060, 17061, 17062, 
17063, 17064, 17065, 17066, 17067, 17068, 17069, 17070, 17071, 
17072, 17073, 17074, 17046, 17047, 17048, 17049, 17050, 17051, 
17052, 17053, 17054, 17055, 17056, 17057, 17058, 17059, 17060, 
17061, 17062, 17063, 17064, 17065, 17066, 17067, 17068, 17069, 
17070, 17071, 17072, 17073, 17074, 17046, 17047, 17048, 17049, 
17050, 17051, 17052, 17053, 17054, 17055, 17056, 17057, 17058, 
17059, 17060, 17061, 17062, 17063, 17064, 17065, 17066, 17067, 
17068, 17069, 17070, 17071, 17072, 17073, 17074, 17046, 17047, 
17048, 17049, 17050, 17051, 17052, 17053, 17054, 17055, 17056, 
17057, 17058, 17059, 17060, 17061, 17062, 17063, 17064, 17065, 
17066, 17067, 17068, 17069, 17070, 17071, 17072, 17073, 17074, 
17046, 17047, 17048, 17049, 17050, 17051, 17052, 17053, 17054, 
17055, 17056, 17057, 17058, 17059, 17060, 17061, 17062, 17063, 
17064, 17065, 17066, 17067, 17068, 17069, 17070, 17071, 17072, 
17073, 17074, 17046, 17047, 17048, 17049, 17050, 17051, 17052, 
17053, 17054, 17055, 17056, 17057, 17058, 17059, 17060, 17061, 
17062, 17063, 17064, 17065, 17066, 17067, 17068, 17069, 17070, 
17071, 17072, 17073, 17074, 17046, 17047, 17048, 17049, 17050, 
17051, 17052, 17053, 17054, 17055, 17056, 17057, 17058, 17059, 
17060, 17061, 17062, 17063, 17064, 17065, 17066, 17067, 17068, 
17069, 17070, 17071, 17072, 17073, 17074, 17046, 17047, 17048, 
17049, 17050, 17051, 17052, 17053, 17054, 17055, 17056, 17057, 
17058, 17059, 17060, 17061, 17062, 17063, 17064, 17065, 17066, 
17067, 17068, 17069, 17070, 17071, 17072, 17073, 17074), class = "Date"), 
    Station = c("RIC", "RIC", "RIC", "RIC", "RIC", "RIC", "RIC", 
    "RIC", "RIC", "RIC", "RIC", "RIC", "RIC", "RIC", "RIC", "RIC", 
    "RIC", "RIC", "RIC", "RIC", "RIC", "RIC", "RIC", "RIC", "RIC", 
    "RIC", "RIC", "RIC", "RIC", "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", 
    "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", 
    "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", 
    "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", "ORF", "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", 
    "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", 
    "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", 
    "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", "DCA", "MRB", 
    "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", 
    "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", 
    "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", "MRB", 
    "MRB", "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", 
    "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", 
    "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", 
    "NHK", "NHK", "NHK", "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", 
    "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", 
    "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", 
    "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", "GSO", "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", 
    "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", 
    "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", 
    "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", "TRI", "CHO", "CHO", 
    "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", 
    "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", 
    "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", "CHO", 
    "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", 
    "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", 
    "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", "IAD", 
    "IAD", "IAD", "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", 
    "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", 
    "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", 
    "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", "LYH", "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", 
    "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", 
    "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", 
    "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", "NYG", "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", 
    "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", 
    "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", 
    "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", "PHF", "ROA", 
    "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", 
    "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", 
    "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", "ROA", 
    "ROA", "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", 
    "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", 
    "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", 
    "WAL", "WAL", "WAL", "BKW", "BKW", "BKW", "BKW", "BKW", "BKW", 
    "BKW", "BKW", "BKW", "BKW", "BKW", "BKW", "BKW", "BKW", "BKW", 
    "BKW", "BKW", "BKW", "BKW", "BKW", "BKW", "BKW", "BKW", "BKW", 
    "BKW", "BKW", "BKW", "BKW", "BKW"), Class = c("MT", "MM", 
    "DM", "DM", "DT", "MT", "MT", "MT+", "MT", "T", "DM", "MT", 
    "MT", "MM", "DM", "MT", "MT", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MM", "DM", 
    "MT", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MT", "T", "MM", 
    "MT", "DT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "DM", "DT", 
    "MM", "MM", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MT", "MT", 
    "DM", "DM", "MM", "MT", "MM", "MM", "DM", "MT", "DM", "DT", 
    "DT", "MT+", "MT+", "MT+", "MT+", "T", "DM", "MT", "T", "MT", 
    "DM", "MT", "MT", "MM", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MM", "DM", 
    "MM", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MP", "DM", "DM", "DM", "DT", "DT", 
    "T", "DT", "MT+", "MT", "DT", "DM", "DM", "DT", "MM", "MM", 
    "MT", "MT", "MM", "MT", "DM", "DM", "DM", "DM", "DM", "MM", 
    "DM", "MM", "MM", "MP", "MT", "MT", "DM", "DM", "DT", "MT", 
    "MT+", "MT+", "MT", "T", "DM", "MT", "MT", "MT", "DM", "MT", 
    "MT", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MT", "MT", "MM", "DM", "MM", "MM", 
    "MM", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MT", "MT", "DM", "DT", "MT+", "DT", 
    "DT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", 
    "MT", "MT", "MM", "MM", "MT", "DT", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MM", 
    "MT", "MT", "MT", "DM", "DM", "DM", "DM", "DM", "MT", "MT", 
    "DT", "DM", "DT", "DT", "DM", "DT", "DT", "DT", "MM", "MT", 
    "MT", "DM", "MT", "DM", "DM", "DM", "MT", "MM", "T", "MP", 
    "MP", "DM", "DM", "DM", "DM", "DT", "MT+", "MT+", "DT+", 
    "DT", "T", "DM", "MT", "DT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", 
    "MT", "MT", "DM", "DM", "MT", "MM", "MM", "MT", "MM", "MM", 
    "MP", "DM", "DM", "DM", "DT", "DT", "MT", "DT", "DT", "DT", 
    "T", "DM", "DM", "DT", "DM", "DM", "MT", "MT", "MM", "MT", 
    "MT", "DM", "DT", "MM", "DM", "MM", "DM", "MM", "MM", "MP", 
    "MT", "DM", "DM", "DM", "DT", "DT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "T", 
    "DM", "MT", "DT", "MM", "MM", "MT", "MT", "MM", "MT", "MM", 
    "MT", "DM", "MT", "MM", "MM", "MT", "MM", "MM", "MM", "DM", 
    "MT", "DM", "DM", "DT", "T", "MT", "MT", "MT", "T", "DM", 
    "MT", "DT", "MT", "MM", "MT", "MT", "MM", "MT", "MT", "DM", 
    "MT", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MT", "T", 
    "MT", "DM", "DT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "DM", 
    "MT", "MM", "MM", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MT", 
    "MT", "MM", "DM", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MT", "DM", "DM", 
    "DM", "DT", "DT", "MT+", "MT+", "MT", "T", "DM", "MT", "DT", 
    "MT", "MM", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MT", "DM", "DM", "MT", 
    "MM", "MM", "MT", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MT", "T", "MT", "DM", 
    "DT", "MT", "MT", "MT+", "MT", "MT", "MT", "DM", "MT", "MM", 
    "DM", "MT", "MT", "MT", "MM", "MM", "MM", "MT", "MM", "DM", 
    "T", "MM", "MM", "T", "MM", "DM", "DM", "DM", "DM", "DM", 
    "MT", "MT", "MT", "DT", "DM", "DM", "DM", "T", "DM", "MT", 
    "MT", "MM", "MM", "DM", "DM", "DM", "DM", "DM", "DM", "MM", 
    "T", "T", "MM", "MM")), row.names = c(125L, 126L, 127L, 128L, 
129L, 130L, 131L, 132L, 133L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 139L, 
140L, 141L, 142L, 143L, 144L, 145L, 146L, 147L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 
151L, 152L, 153L, 278L, 279L, 280L, 281L, 282L, 283L, 284L, 285L, 
286L, 287L, 288L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 
297L, 298L, 299L, 300L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 306L, 431L, 
432L, 433L, 434L, 435L, 436L, 437L, 438L, 439L, 440L, 441L, 442L, 
443L, 444L, 445L, 446L, 447L, 448L, 449L, 450L, 451L, 452L, 453L, 
454L, 455L, 456L, 457L, 458L, 459L, 584L, 585L, 586L, 587L, 588L, 
589L, 590L, 591L, 592L, 593L, 594L, 595L, 596L, 597L, 598L, 599L, 
600L, 601L, 602L, 603L, 604L, 605L, 606L, 607L, 608L, 609L, 610L, 
611L, 612L, 737L, 738L, 739L, 740L, 741L, 742L, 743L, 744L, 745L, 
746L, 747L, 748L, 749L, 750L, 751L, 752L, 753L, 754L, 755L, 756L, 
757L, 758L, 759L, 760L, 761L, 762L, 763L, 764L, 765L, 890L, 891L, 
892L, 893L, 894L, 895L, 896L, 897L, 898L, 899L, 900L, 901L, 902L, 
903L, 904L, 905L, 906L, 907L, 908L, 909L, 910L, 911L, 912L, 913L, 
914L, 915L, 916L, 917L, 918L, 1043L, 1044L, 1045L, 1046L, 1047L, 
1048L, 1049L, 1050L, 1051L, 1052L, 1053L, 1054L, 1055L, 1056L, 
1057L, 1058L, 1059L, 1060L, 1061L, 1062L, 1063L, 1064L, 1065L, 
1066L, 1067L, 1068L, 1069L, 1070L, 1071L, 1196L, 1197L, 1198L, 
1199L, 1200L, 1201L, 1202L, 1203L, 1204L, 1205L, 1206L, 1207L, 
1208L, 1209L, 1210L, 1211L, 1212L, 1213L, 1214L, 1215L, 1216L, 
1217L, 1218L, 1219L, 1220L, 1221L, 1222L, 1223L, 1224L, 1349L, 
1350L, 1351L, 1352L, 1353L, 1354L, 1355L, 1356L, 1357L, 1358L, 
1359L, 1360L, 1361L, 1362L, 1363L, 1364L, 1365L, 1366L, 1367L, 
1368L, 1369L, 1370L, 1371L, 1372L, 1373L, 1374L, 1375L, 1376L, 
1377L, 1502L, 1503L, 1504L, 1505L, 1506L, 1507L, 1508L, 1509L, 
1510L, 1511L, 1512L, 1513L, 1514L, 1515L, 1516L, 1517L, 1518L, 
1519L, 1520L, 1521L, 1522L, 1523L, 1524L, 1525L, 1526L, 1527L, 
1528L, 1529L, 1530L, 1655L, 1656L, 1657L, 1658L, 1659L, 1660L, 
1661L, 1662L, 1663L, 1664L, 1665L, 1666L, 1667L, 1668L, 1669L, 
1670L, 1671L, 1672L, 1673L, 1674L, 1675L, 1676L, 1677L, 1678L, 
1679L, 1680L, 1681L, 1682L, 1683L, 1808L, 1809L, 1810L, 1811L, 
1812L, 1813L, 1814L, 1815L, 1816L, 1817L, 1818L, 1819L, 1820L, 
1821L, 1822L, 1823L, 1824L, 1825L, 1826L, 1827L, 1828L, 1829L, 
1830L, 1831L, 1832L, 1833L, 1834L, 1835L, 1836L, 1961L, 1962L, 
1963L, 1964L, 1965L, 1966L, 1967L, 1968L, 1969L, 1970L, 1971L, 
1972L, 1973L, 1974L, 1975L, 1976L, 1977L, 1978L, 1979L, 1980L, 
1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 1988L, 1989L, 
2114L, 2115L, 2116L, 2117L, 2118L, 2119L, 2120L, 2121L, 2122L, 
2123L, 2124L, 2125L, 2126L, 2127L, 2128L, 2129L, 2130L, 2131L, 
2132L, 2133L, 2134L, 2135L, 2136L, 2137L, 2138L, 2139L, 2140L, 
2141L, 2142L, 2267L, 2268L, 2269L, 2270L, 2271L, 2272L, 2273L, 
2274L, 2275L, 2276L, 2277L, 2278L, 2279L, 2280L, 2281L, 2282L, 
2283L, 2284L, 2285L, 2286L, 2287L, 2288L, 2289L, 2290L, 2291L, 
2292L, 2293L, 2294L, 2295L), class = "data.frame")
```

I would like to plot to look like this(this is full dataset, Data is a subset):
[Ideal plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnFRy.png)

However, when I run this code I get numerical values on the Y-axis rather than station names:

```
ggplot() +
  labs(x= "Date") +
  geom_bar(data = SSC,
           aes(fill = Class, x = Date)) +
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: `ggplot(SCC, aes(Date, Station, fill = Class)) + geom_tile()`? Then you might want to customize further by making `Class` and `Station` into ordered factors so they plot in your preferred order instead of alphabetically. `forcats::fct_inorder` or `forcats::fct_reorder` might be helpful for that.